# Base64 getting error when compile java source in Oracle sql

Tags: java, grails, oracle11g, sha256, hmac

I'm able to create a function to compare hash data between my web project(`Grails project`) and `sql query` result.

According to this [link](http://www.jokecamp.com/blog/examples-of-creating-base64-hashes-using-hmac-sha256-in-different-languages/),

- I apply groovy code into groovy class, then I got the result.
- In query, first I compile `java source`, then `compile function`, and call function.

However, I got trouble when tried to `import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64`. 
Code below:

```
create or replace and compile java source named testhmacSHA256 as
import javax.crypto.Mac;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
public class testhmacSHA256 {
  public static String encrypt(String secret, String message) { 
  try {
      Mac sha256_HMAC = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
     SecretKeySpec secret_key = new SecretKeySpec(secret.getBytes(), "HmacSHA256");
     sha256_HMAC.init(secret_key);

     String hash = Base64.encodeBase64String(sha256_HMAC.doFinal(message.getBytes()));
     return hash;
    }
    catch (Exception e){
     System.out.println("Error");
    }
  }
}
/
```

Obviously, Base64 can't be found. 
So my question is that is there any alternative way for importing `base64`, or just a way to use `hmac-sha 256` in `oracle sql 11g`.

Any helps will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you just add http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec to your project?

Comment: Hi, project works fine. you mean add to the oracle sql, don't you? How can I add it to oracle 11g? Thanks.

Comment: No. You wrote "_However, I got trouble when tried to import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64_" so I understood that you can not import this class. If we misunderstood each other than please explain your problem in another way.

Comment: So, let me explain. Here is the flow: create and compile Java source -> create a function base on that source -> call a function. I struck in compile java source step, console shows org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64 cannot found

Answer (score 0):

Open **conf/BuildConfig.groovy** and in section **dependency** add:

```
build "commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10"
```

it should like:

```
dependency {
    //... another dependiences if any
    build "commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10"
}
```

Refresh dependiences and recompile project.

If you have any problems please paste in question your conf/BuildConfig.groovy source file.